# Does G-d's overt presence invalidate one's free choice?

Tags: theology, free-will-bechira

It is frequently claimed that the reason for the current Haster Panim (lack of G-d's overt presence in the physical world) is that it is necessary for our free choice. In other words, if G-d's presence is obvious, the Torah keeping is also automatic.

However, the Torah describes many occasions when people sinned freely even after having personal experiences with G-d, proving exactly the opposite:

- Adam sinned, Kain also killed a man while being born in Eden
- the Israelites sinned with the Golden calf after perceiving G-d in Matan Torah
- Moses sinned by hitting the rock
- Yona ran away from G-d's commandment

So does G-d's overt presence invalidate one's free choice or not?

Comment: You mean the "intellectual perception" of the existence of g.d?

Comment: Does it have to be free or not free?  How about something in between?  "Inhibited"?

Comment: “Frequently claimed” Any sources?

Comment: The events you cite on your answer is that G-d's presence does not compromise free will.

Comment: overt knowledge of truth doesn't make impossible to do a mistake.

Comment: Wait - you are ignoring the fact that after a time you forget...