# Does explicit revelation really take away our free will?

Tags: science, free-will-bechira

I've seen it expressed in various answers and comments here (and elsewhere in general) that Hashem did not reveal things like explicit scientific knowledge in the Torah, performs regular open miracles, etc.  because this would take away our free will.

However, the people who experienced G-d's revelation at Sinai did not lose their free will, and neither did those who saw open miracles in later generations. So what justifies the use of arguments of the type "there's no [this or that type of evidence] because it would take away our free will"?

Comment: duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109518/759

Comment: true it's a duplicate, but the original received no answers (and hardly any comments). Maybe this one will?

Comment: So many conversations become easier when we define our terms. People mean different things but use the same words. What do you mean by "free" when speaking of freedom of the will?

Comment: There are two sides here : 1) statements from those who say revelation takes away free will and 2) the fact that people who experienced revelation at Sinai didn't lose their free will.

I'm saying that under any (or most) fixed interpretation/definition of 'free will', 1) and 2) seem to contradict each other.

Perhaps there is some definition of 'free will' where they do not contradict, and that could be the subject of an answer.

Comment: to clarify, 1) and 2) always (syntactically) contradict each other, it is just that we can reinterpret 'free will' in one of them to mean something else (and hence replace that term with a more nuanced one), to resolve the contradiction

Comment: You also need to define losing free will. For example, there is a dispute about how mal'akhim lack free will: (1) they lack the capacity to choose, or (2) they have such clear understanding of the situation, there are no choices to be made.