Eradication of Free Will under a functioning Biblical legal system or Talmudic education
It is frequently argued that the lack of direct Heavenly intervention in the Creation was designed to allow for a free "pressure-free" choice between good and bad. E.g. when a person breaks Shabbos, eats non-Kosher food, or has illicit relations, no immediate and direct Godly retribution is observed, because otherwise, free will would be revoked, a person would turn into a puppet, and the idea of Heavenly reward and punishment would be invalidated.
On the other hand, God explicitly commands us, humans, to establish a system of courts and police with tight surveillance and harsh and dreadful punishments, e.g. (Deut 17):

"And the man that will act presumptuously, and will not hearken to the priest that stands to minister there before thy God, or to the judge, that man shall die: and thou shalt put away the evil from Yisra᾽el.
And all the people shall hear, and fear, and do no more presumptuously."

In other words, a powerful and properly functioning legal system that enforces Biblical laws represents the opposite of the cultivation of personal free will.
The Talmud advocates for a similar approach in educating children about Torah and Mitzvot, emphasizing corporal punishment as a means to instill a deep-rooted aversion to sin through learned behavior.
How do our sources deal with this contradiction?

N.B. I understand that historically, the idea of free will was developed in the times when Jewish Sanhedrins ceased to exist under Roman rule, and Jewish transgressors were left to the "Heavenly court". I would only like to see if any pro-free-will commentators noticed this contradiction.

The solution is to do evil without the presence of witness, or do acts that are "menuval b'rshut hadin"

People see bad behavior punished, and still choose to act poorly. It's just one more input. (There are people who watch friends die early of lung cancer and still smoke. There are folks who've had chunks of their windpipe removed because of smoking, and then they smoke through their throat stoma.)

@Shalom related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109518/does-g-ds-overt-presence-invalidate-ones-free-choice?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C35.8748

This is an attempt to answer based on my understanding (and as I can tell from the comments, the understanding of other as well)
The concept of free choice means that it is a person has the freedom to choose his actions and is not forced by anyone to choose one way or the other.
Having a court system that imposes death penalties, lashes or fines can act as deterrences but they do not force someone to act a certain way.
On a side note, just to address some of the points made in by the OP

the sifrei mussar say that the reason Hashem doesn't punish immediately at time of transgression is to give the transgression time and ability to repent (sources to follow)
most transgressions do not carry death penalties, and no lashes exist when one does not observe מצוות עשה. Even when punishments can be given by bais din, one needs witnesses and warnings. This leaves ample room to not observe mitzvoth without the fear of punishment.


Thank you. My question tries to examine the concept of coercion in Torah observance that seemingly contradicts the idea of free will. The Torah is very clear that force must be used to steer people from sin in the absence of divine intervention. While addressing some minor cases, you overlooked the principle and ignored the use of force in education. What do you think about the latter?

@AlBerko i don't believe free will means to leave everyone uneducated of the pitfalls. The yetzer hora is strong, and as stated in the Talmud, without Torah study (which is the education you mention) one will not succeed. But again, this is not contradicting free will.

I didn't mean Torah study, I meant חוסך שבטו שונא בנו - the practice of harsh physical punishment endorsed by the Talmud and practiced in all Torah schools until recently.

I'm not sure how to source this answer; it is the accumulation of a lot of learning but if anything specific I say strikes you, feel free to request a source.
Hashem balances every aspect of life so that we should have free will. For example, Hashem creates it that the yeitzer hara is more attracted to the forbidden, and finds it harder to do good that is expected vs. good "that comes from the heart". This contradicts what we might think, that forbidding something makes it harder for people to choose, or demanding something makes it easier for them.
Another way Hashem ensures free will is by equalizing pleasure. If only good things "tasted good", we would have no trouble being good and avoiding evil. However, it is not like that, and as above, sometimes the forbidden tastes better!
I don't think we need to have a very analytical answer as to how Hashem ensures free will. His ways are too numerous and holistic for us to fathom, not that we can fathom His vast thoughts in general!
I will note though that the Lubavitcher Rebbe makes a very related point - we are living in a time where there is very little "pressure" to do the right thing. This is unprecedented in Jewish History, whether it be that we were on the Land seeing open miracles, or living in Ghettoes where being religious was the ticket to good business and shidduchim for our children, there has, until today, always been something detracting from our good deeds being "lishma".
The whole of history has been a gradual "letting go" of our hand from Hashem, letting us learn to crawl and then walk and seeing how we can behave "by ourself", to get a true measure of our goodness through giving us "truer and truer" free will.
We can trace this from the point of the Megilla, that Hashem's name is not mentioned, and all miracles are "hidden", so as not to provide "supernatural pressure" on us to be good. This state of affairs was so lofty and beneficial, we are described as "only then" having truly accepted the Torah, due to our great response to those challenges.
We can even trace it further back still, and there are sichot that we were initially given a chance to play around with our freedom before the flood, and look what we did. After that, we were more restrained in our freedom by witnessing great leaders, miracles etc. The goal was to refine us internally, with the end result that we should have our hands "let go" again towards the end of history, and we will see that indeed, we have changed and become good deep down.
tl;dr So, this answer is basically saying that no, it is not a contradiction, it does indeed affect our free will. However, Hashem has ways of balancing that out, and even if not, there is a purpose to our free will being more restrained at certain times, and more "truly free" at other times.

Thank you. My question wasn't about the existence of free will, it only pointed to the contradiction between rabbinic apologetics and the Biblical and rabbinic practices, for example, the endorsement of corporal punishment in kids' education that was common until recently. tldr, you sound like "I dunno, that's the way Hashem works". The contradiction is there, and the Talmud commands us to inflict pain and horror onto our kids and the general public to straighten them up.

IIRC, the Septuagint version of Ester does have several verses mentioning God's name.

@AlBerko You're welcome! I thought I did answer that, indirectly. Perhaps we should start a chat to clarify and I can try and improve the answer? Thanks for the great questions as always, I really enjoy the way you think

I asked a prominent UO Posek in Meah Shearim about the practice of using anaphrodisiac (anti-libido) drugs in Yeshivas (in Israel): Shouldn't rabbis be taking the fun of coping with "Heavenly tests", "free will" of being aroused? Guess what he answered. In my understanding, there's a sort of rabbinic hypocrisy: while the Gemmora in Brochos 34 praises Baale Teshuva, the Orthodox world prefers Tzaddikim who never tasted the taste of sin, basically never had experienced "free will" or free choice.

@AlBerko there's a reason for that I believe, would you like to open a chat?

Sorry, didn't see your comment. I'm ready now

Here is the chat room. I will start with some thoughts on your last comments, when I get a chance. Not a rushed conversation - reply when we can no pressure @AlBerko
